# How to get string with space in C?

Tags: c, string, file, search

I need to be able to search a file with a user input of a string with possible spaces. I only included the function that searches the file for the city.

```
void searchByCity (resource_t resources[], int count)
{
  char searchCity[LEN_CITY + 1];
  int index;

  printf("Enter a City: ");
  fgets(searchCity, LEN_CITY + 1, stdin);
  //sscanf("%[^\n]", searchCity);

  int searchStrLength = strlen(searchCity);

  for (index = 0; index < count; index++)
{
    if (strncasecmp(resources[index].city, searchCity, searchStrLength)== 0)
    {
        displayOne(&resources[index]);

    }

 }
}
```

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that the trailing newline included by `fgets()` is a strong candidate for your culprit.  I'd like to add that if you're trying to perform an exact match to the user's search string, then you want `strcasecmp()`, not `strncasecmp()`.  You would want the latter only if you want to perform a prefix match or if you cannot rely on your strings to be properly terminated.  (And in the latter case, you would probably want the last argument to be the buffer size, not the string length; a few other small changes would be needed to do it right, as well.)

Comment: Consider the city names in `resources[]` are well formed with no excess space Like "New York", "Chicago" , "Saint Paul".  User input may have leading, trailing or excessive inter-space like `" New   \tYork \r\n"` or use abbreviations like `"St. Paul"` or run things together like `"NewYorK"`.  Recommend posting sample data, sample input and expected output.